# Visual Studio Code JDBC Acess to Derby Database

Tags: java, jdbc, visual-studio-code, derby

I am trying to run a java program (demo program included in the Apache Derby installation folder called *SimpleApp*) that connects to a Derby database using JDBC, in Visual Studio Code (with an integrated terminal), but I keep getting the same error message:

```
>java SimpleApp

SimpleApp starting in embedded mode
----- SQLException -----
   SQL State: 08001
   Error Code: 0
   Message: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:derbyDB;create=true
SimpleApp finished
```

I ran the SimpleApp java file in the command prompt and it worked just fine:

```
>java SimpleApp

SimpleApp starting in embedded mode
Connected to and created database derbyDB
Created table location
Inserted 1956 Webster
Inserted 1910 Union
Updated 1956 Webster to 180 Grand
Updated 180 Grand to 300 Lakeshore
Verified the rows
Dropped table location
Committed the transaction
Derby shut down normally
SimpleApp finished
```

---

I am using the following:

- [Windows 10 OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10)
- [Visual Studio Code 1.29](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_29)
- [JDK 11.0.1](https://jdk.java.net/11/)
- [Apache Derby 10.14.2.0](https://db.apache.org/derby/releases/release-10.14.2.0.cgi)
- [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) (vs code extension)

I have the following settings:

- JDK path in VS Code:
  `"java.home": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.1"`
- JAVA_HOME system variable:
  `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1`
- DERBY_HOME system variable:
  `C:\Program Files\Apache\db-derby-10.14.2.0-bin`
- CLASSPATH system variable:
  `.;%JAVA_HOME%\lib;%DERBY_HOME%\lib\derby.jar;%DERBY_HOME%\lib\derbytools.jar;`
- In the Path system variable:
  `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` and `%DERBY_HOME%\bin`

---

Some notes from the SimpleApp java file:

> This sample program is a minimal Java application showing JDBC access
>   to a Derby database. Derby applications can run against Derby running
>   in an embedded or a client/server framework. When Derby runs in an
>   embedded framework, the JDBC application and Derby run in the same
>   Java Virtual Machine (JVM). The application starts up the Derby
>   engine. When Derby runs in a client/server framework, the application
>   runs in a different JVM from Derby. The connectivity framework (in
>   this case the Derby Network Server) provides network connections. The
>   client driver is loaded automatically.

Comment: I guess that you will need to set your classpath within Visual Studio

Comment: Most ways of executing Java applications **do not** use the `CLASSPATH` environment variable; don't rely on it and instead configure the classpath specifically for the application.

Comment: Try printing out the value of `CLASSPATH` from within your program, before you attempt to open the JDBC connection, and see what value your program is actually getting.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know what I did but now it works... @BryanPendleton I tried printing out the classpath by copying and pasting the code from [this website](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-print-out-the-current-project-classpath/) and an error printed out. I wasn't sure what to do so I merely went back to my original code and tried to connect to the database. It somehow worked. I then ran the SimpleApp code and that also worked... I have no idea why. Thanks guys.

Comment: Perhaps you are using a client/server configuration of Derby, and your Derby Network Server is sometimes down, and sometimes up?